# Java regex for remove no digit chracter except decimal point

Tags: java, regex

I have following strings:

```
S/. 05.56
S/. 0.0
S/. 0.00
S/. 90.10
S/.   01.23
S/.   1.00   
S/.1.80
$/.9.80
$/.  10.80
$/.    89.81
$    89.81
```

I need this output

```
05.56
0.0
0.00
90.10
01.23
1.00
1.80
9.80
10.80
89.81
```

I need to remove all non-digit character before first number, Then regex haven't to remove decimal point

I tried this regex but doesn't work:

```
e.replaceAll("[a-zA-z](/.)( )*", ""); //don't remove $
e.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""); //This show .3.4 I need remove the first point decimal
```

I need to remove all monetary symbol

Thanks for help!

Comment: What if input is `$/ .25`, should it become `25` or `.25`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `^\\D+` to replace all non-digits from the beginning of each string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] str = { "S/. 05.56", "S/. 0.0", "S/. 0.00", "S/. 90.10", "S/.   01.23", "S/.   1.00", "S/.1.80",
            "$/.9.80", "$/.  10.80", "$/.    89.81", "$    89.81" };

    for (String s : str) {
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^\\D+", ""));
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
05.56
0.0
0.00
90.10
01.23
1.00
1.80
9.80
10.80
89.81
89.81
```

Comment: To elaborate on the regex itself: `^` anchors the search to the start of the string. `\\D` matches all non-digit characters (a second slash is necessary to escape the otherwise special single-backslash), and `+` means "one or more characters". Regexes are greedy, so the one-or-more will match as many non-digits as possible, until the first digit it encounters.

Comment: If I have an string like this: 1.23.24 and I want a regex that only show 1.23, How  will the regex be?

Comment: It doesn't work for this string $1,000.00" the result is this one: "1,000.00" then if you convert that to a double it crashes.