# Regex replace all characters before a numeric value in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

So I want to replace all content from a String before a numeric value. Meaning that we only keep the numeric value and everything following it. I want to remove "Algade" (also ignoring White space) so I only have "123"
After trying through my knowledge on Regex expressions this is what I eventually came up with.
I am looking for a regex-expression that will clear all characters before a number despite what comes after the numbers being numeric/string chars.

```
String test = "Algade 123 th. 1";

String removeBeforenr = test.replaceAll("^\\D(\\d)", "");
```

// Desired result:   "123 th. 1";

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, I am very familiar with regex expressions. I have battled so long to make this work and Havent been able to find a solution. This is not me asking a lazy question, but merely ,me looking for professional insight to help me.

Comment: Great, then just add your best attempt to the question and explain what the problem is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Just did in the edited question :D

Comment: So, you want `test.replaceAll("\\D+", "");`? I edited the dupe link.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes in a sense. However, i do work with string values that look like "algade 123 th. 12"  - And with a "\\D+" expression it does not replace the values before the first number. It instead keeps the whole string value unchanged

Comment: You see, that is why I asked to add the details to explain what is wrong. Please add all the details like that to the question.

Comment: Does it mean you just want to extract the first number from a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no what i want is the remove everything from a String that comes before the first number found in the string. I have further elaborated in my updated question.

Comment: Ok, use `.replaceFirst("^\\D+", "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you so much, sir. That was exactly what I needed. Can I ping ur comment as the solution ? :D

Comment: I have found [Java regex for remove no digit chracter except decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396239/java-regex-for-remove-no-digit-chracter-except-decimal-point) dupe reason that contains the solution.